# Hacer visible propiedad para pruebas en enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

¿Existe algún equivalente al `@VisibleForTesting` de [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) en enzyme que me permita acceder a una función o valor privado de un componente de React únicamente para pruebas unitarias?

Actualmente esto es lo que tengo:

```
describe('Anchor Render', () => {
.
.
.
  it('should remove listener when unmount', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount<Anchor>(
      <Anchor>
        <Link href="#API" title="API" />
      </Anchor>,
    );
    const removeListenerSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance().scrollEvent, 'remove');
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(removeListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Y tsc me manda el mensaje :

> Error:(241, 61) TS2341: Property 'scrollEvent' is private and only accessible within class 'Anchor'.

Comment: ¿Has probado `shallow` en vez de `mount`? https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallow-rendering-api

Comment: mismo resultado :/

Comment: I found this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182297/jest-enzyme-test-event-listener-removed.

Comment: Produciría el mismo resultado ya que se trataría de acceder a un método privado en el primer parámetro de `spyOn`

Comment: Produce el mismo resultado `remove` que `removeEventListener` ?

Comment: sí, es problema con typescript, si lo paso a JS las pruebas pasan sin problema